# Advice on how to search for products with criteria

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a asp.net website and in the masterpage I have some dropdown controls where the user selects criteria for products.
After the last selected dropdown box I send the selected values to another page which is child to masterpage and I make a query to the database and present the results in a gridview.

My problem is that the masterpage is refreshed and all the selected values are cleared.
How can I keep the values to masterpage dropdown boxes or is there any better solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added an invisible Panel in the Masterpage and hide all the controls inside. Instead of posting to another page i'm filling the controls with the data and reveal the Panel.
I found that this is faster and easier.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The Master Page will never keep data if you redirect to another page, the only thing you can do is to use session variables. You can "mask" the session values using static variables:

```
public static string MyValue
    {
        get { return (string)HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"];}
        set { HttpContext.Current.Session["MyValue"] = value; }
    }
```

Assign the values to your "static" variables before doing the redirection, and in the Page_Load of the Master Page you can read those values and assign everyone to the respective controls. For example:

In Page1.aspx.cs:

```
public void DoRedirect()
{
    SiteMaster.MyValue = txtControlPage1.Text;
    Response.Redirect("~/Page2.aspx", true);
}
```

When the Page2.aspx is loaded, the Page_Load of the Master Page will be called and you can do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Page_Load of Site.Master.cs
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        txtSomeControl.Text = SiteMaster.MyValue;
        MyUpdatePanel.Update();
    }
}
```

No matter how many pages you will redirect, the Master Page will always read the values from your static variables and all you need is to assign values before do the redirection.

Comment: When i'am in the same page, i'm not losing data, the grid to show the results is in another page. I'm losing data when i execute the response.redirect to go to the other page.
If everything is on same page is not a problem but the dropdowns are on MasterPage and the Grid is on another page.